# CoPay Limits per day

Tags: wallet, copay

Does anyone know if there are limits to the amount of BTC that can be moved in and out of a Copay Multi sig wallet please either on a daily basis or in total or both ?

Answer (score 2):

There are no limits set by the wallet itself. As long as the co-signers agree you can do what you like.

Comment: Ok thank you. Appreciate your answer...and in terms of support in the event of a problem...Is the support on the Github site ?

Comment: It's open source software so support will be community support only. There are many community forums like bitcointalk.org and subreddits /r/bitcoin and /r/bitcoinbeginners. Note there are other open source wallets as well. You can compare them [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet).

Comment: Note that Bitpay, the maintainer, is essentially not maintaining this software. It is terribly out of date and vulnerable at this point. There is very good reason not to use it.

Comment: Thanks Eponymous....are there other simple elegant alternative Multi Sig wallets you would suggest please ?

Comment: @eponymous why do you say that? last release was a week ago.

Comment: @Abdussamad  Their own demo instance and backend is still using Bitcoin Core 0.12, which is incredibly obsolete at this point. https://insight.bitpay.com/api/status?q=getInfo

Comment: There's been effectively no development of the software to speak of for years, other than adding support for bcash and [hard linking it](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api/commit/ff4e30c1fa125cf0f12cd14db3f391f0227a1984#diff-6d186b954a58d5bb740f73d84fe39073R48) into the software.